# keep internet connection running after closing RDP (AWS instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I run a computation via a browser on a Windows AWS instance connected by a RDP.

This needs to have a internet connection. But if I close the RDP window, the instance is running, but it seems to have issues with the internet connection.
This connections seems lost when closing.

Does anyone has an idea how to avoid this while closing the RDP?

Comment: This seems unlikely. Please post more debug info.

Comment: Maybe it is due to some restriction in the settings? Spcially this happens when using google cholab...